# How do I find the number of elements in a column greater than a given number in Linux?

Tags: linux, encoding

I have a text file of list of students with Marks and I want to find how many of them secured more than 80 in Maths, Physics and then Maths and Physics combined. What should be the Linux command to do this?

The text file is here:

```
#name maths phy
Manila 78 29
Shikhar 49 78
Vandana 65 87
Priyansh 75 22
Bina 52 69
Chitransh 98 93
William 88 73
Kaushal 38 85
Dilruba 65 94
Lalremruata 34 45
Qasim 58 62
Nitya 81 89
Jennita 96 91
Shobha 71 63
Talim 77 88
```

Comment: What do you mean with _combined_? the average, the maximum, the minimum.... can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using `awk` (don't use `grep` because this is not fit for number arithmetic). An example:

```
cat test.txt | awk '{if ($2>80 || $3>80) print $1 " " $2 " " $3}'
```

This needs to be improved: how to remove the `cat` command, how to check the sum of both columns, why is the title present, ...? But at least you have something to start.

Comment: Thanks for the help but how do I obtain the number of such students directly? Where do I place the count variable?

Comment: In order to count a result in UNIX, you just add ` | wc -l` after it. Don't forget that the title bar is also included, so you might need to subtract one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and adapt it to your taste:

```
$ awk '/^[^#]/{
    limit = 80;
    comb = $2 + $3;
    if ($2 > limit && $3 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "both";
    else if ($2 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "maths";
    else if ($3 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "physics";
    else if (comb > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "combined";
}' <<EOF
#name maths phy
Manila 78 29
Shikhar 49 78
Vandana 65 87
Priyansh 75 22
Bina 52 69
Chitransh 98 93
William 88 73
Kaushal 38 85
Dilruba 65 94
Lalremruata 34 45
Qasim 58 62
Nitya 81 89
Jennita 96 91
Shobha 71 63
Talim 77 88 
EOF
```

which produces the following:

```
Manila 78 29 combined
Shikhar 49 78 combined
Vandana 65 87 physics
Priyansh 75 22 combined
Bina 52 69 combined
Chitransh 98 93 both
William 88 73 maths
Kaushal 38 85 physics
Dilruba 65 94 physics
Qasim 58 62 combined
Nitya 81 89 both
Jennita 96 91 both
Shobha 71 63 combined
Talim 77 88 physics
```

If you want it to be read from a file, then use it as:

```
$ awk '/^[^#]/{
    limit = 80;
    comb = $2 + $3;
    if ($2 > limit && $3 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "both";
    else if ($2 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "maths";
    else if ($3 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "physics";
    else if (comb > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "combined";
}' marks.txt
```

the `awk` script

- will read all lines that have not a `#` in the first column, what will allow you to introduce comments, as the header with the course name.
- will permit you to configure easily a trigger level, as the limit variable is initialized in one place and used as a constant.
- you can adapt the criterion to what you want to get, even the students that don't pass any of the two courses.

## Note:

If you want to do variable substitution inside the `awk` script, beware that `awk` uses `$<n>` notation to refer to input words, which is also used and expanded by the shell, so you you need to do shell variable expansion, the best approach is to close the single quotes and open double quotes on the variable to be expanded only, so you don't get confused which variable will be expanded by the shell and which by `awk`.  Example:

```
$ export TRIGGER=95
$ awk '/^[^#]/{
    limit = '"$TRIGGER"';
    comb = $2 + $3;
    if ($2 > limit && $3 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "both";
    else if ($2 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "maths";
    else if ($3 > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "physics";
    else if (comb > limit)
        print $1, $2, $3, "combined";
}'
```